# amcharts 5- clicking on legend in partitioned-bar-chart to show hide the series is not working

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4, amcharts5

Why series toggling is not working on **partitioned-bar-chart** (https://www.amcharts.com/demos/partitioned-bar-chart/) on click legend.I tried with clickTarget: "marker" property in legend but it is not working. pleas help